# AppStore Connect - Binary Rejected - Performance - App Completeness

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

There is a section for the user to try the application (demo). There is not much content in this section because it is a **demo**. *What should I do
?*

---

**App Review Message:**

From Apple
2. 1 Performance: App Completeness
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Your app or its metadata does not appear to include final content. Specifically, your app includes no content inside the “Demo” section.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please review your app and metadata to ensure that all of its content is final.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Comment: Add details on what you want the user to do in that section, means provide details on how to use that demo section

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without more context on your app but...
Apple does not like apps that feels unfinished, beta or useless.
Try to populate your "demo" section with dummy content so it doesn't look so empty.

For example, if the demo showcases a feature that presents some car specifications to the user you could fill it with details of an example car instead of just showing the empty page:

> Brand: **Peel**
>   Model: **P50**
>   HP: **Not much**
>   [image]

Instead of just:

> Brand:
>   Model:
>   HP:
>   [image]

Comment: There are articles in the application. For some reason, I've been posting articles through webview. When it enters the application, it encounters 100 articles. When he enters the demo, he comes across 3 articles. I can't show too many articles because this is the demo version. 

Is the problem webview or low content ? Instead of updating the application, is it considered to be a demo that says it is a demo ?

Comment: What you can do is showing the complete list of what you will get if you buy the subscription but show them as "locked" and only allow to view the 3 first items.

Comment: Is your "demo" inside your main app or is it a totally different app ?

Comment: in the application. In order to be an example, the android version of the application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emreaydemir.examplus

Comment: Apple comments says that there is *no* content in the demo section. Are you sure that the 3 articles were visible to Apple during the review ?

Comment: Of course I'm sure. Apple complains that there are 3 items in the table view.

Comment: You didn't attach the screenshots mentioned by Apple in your question, but their message says that there is NO content. Anyway, Apple doesn't really like "Demos". I would try to remove that and to display all paying ressources as locked and unlock them when the user subscribes. Additionally, they can reject your app if it's only a webview wrapper and has no other feature. In this case, they will tell you to just make a webapp.

Comment: it's not just a web app. There is also webview within the application, but there was no problem with that part. Delete the demo part and send it again.